# how to restrict javascript function to only accept one argument

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple javascript function that determines the nth fibonacci number. It works, but I am trying to figure out why it still works when it is passed two arguments.

```
function fib(n){
    if (n <= 1){
        return n; 
    }
    else if(n > 1){
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 

    }
}
```

So when I run `fib(10)` I get the correct output of 55. But if I were to do something like

```
fib(1,2)
```

I would expect to get Undefined, but the method is outputting 1.

My question is how can I keep a javascript method to only accept a certain number of arguments? In my case I only want fib to accept one argument.

Comment: You can't, and why would you, it doesn't matter ?

Comment: Well, you could actually, `if (arguments.length > 1) throw Error;`

Comment: It doesn't matter, because you didn't do anything with undefined(second parameter) in your function, you may also return like this: `if (arguments.length > 1) return;`

Comment: I want to know because I don't want it to work with more than one argument. So it does matter. But the answer you provided works thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can't have functions vary just by the number of parameters.  All functions can be called with zero or more parameters.  It's up to the function to determine how and if it will access them (through a mamed parameter or the arguments object) .

Basically you could check and see if more than one argument is available and throw an exception, but why would you do so?  It is unlikely to help you find bugs any faster, and other than that there's no benefit -- the function will operate the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is very forgiving. You could do what you want like adeno mentioned:

`if (arguments.length > 1) throw "Too many arguments exception";`

I really don't see any reason why you should ever do this. You could however worry about the following cases imo.

```
fib(true) // true
fib(false) // false
fib("wat") // undefined
```